# csv module: ordered dictionary manipulation?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with two fields, 'positive' and 'negative'. I am trying to add the positive words to a list from the csv using the DictReader() module. Here is the following code.

```
import csv

with open('pos_neg_cleaned.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
      
    
    positive_list = []
    for n in csv_reader:
        if n == 'positive' and csv_reader[n] != None :
            positive_list.append(csv_reader[n])
```

However the program returns an empty list. Any idea how to get around this issue? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add an example of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can only read once from the csv_reader generator.  In this case your do this with the `print` statement.

With a little re-arranging it should work fine:

```
import csv

with open('pos_neg_cleaned.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    positive_list = []
    for n in csv_reader:
        # put your print statement inside of the generator loop. 
        # otherwise the generator will be empty by the time your run the logic.
        print(n)

        # as n is a dict, you want to grab the right value from that dict.  
        # if it contains a value, then do something with it.
        if n['positive']:
            # Here you want to call the value from your dict.  
            # Don't try to call the csv_reader - but use the given data.
            positive_list.append(n['positive'])
```

Comment: 1) The code is indented properly, I made a mistake in my question while copy pasting.

2) The csv is just a list of words with the respective field names.

Answer (score 0):

Every row in DictReader is a dictionary, so you can retrieve "columns values" using column name as "key" like this:

```
positive_column_values = []
for row in csv_dict_reader:
    positive_column_value = row["positive"]
    positive_column_values.append(positive_column_value)
```

After execution of this code, "positive_column_values" will have all values from "positive" column.

You can replace this code with your code to get desired result:

```
import csv

with open('pos_neg_cleaned.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    positive_list = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        positive_list.append(row["positive"])

print(positive_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way with a list comprehension. It assumes there is a header called `header` that holds (either) `positive` or `negative` values.

```
import csv

with open('pos_neg_cleaned.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    positive_list = [line for line in csv_reader if line.get('header') == 'positive']
    print(positive_list)
```

alternatively if your csv's header is `positive`:

```
    positive_list = [line for line in csv_reader if line.get('positive')]
```